# Date Select Time Zone Issue in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to have datetime_select helper in the user's time zone but I'm having some issues. The setting is the following:

In the controller I set the date:

```
   Time.zone = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
```

Then in the view I have the following:

```
    <%= datetime_select :custom_daily_message, :date, :default => Time.now.in_time_zone %>
```

When I see the view in the browser the date is selected properly in the time zone. Lets say the following:

```
     Fri, 07 Sep 2012 11:20:00 PDT -07:00
```

However when I submitted the form and checked the date in the model it shows the following:

```
     Fri, 07 Sep 2012 11:20:00 UTC +00:00
```

I was expecting the date to be in UTC but with the proper offset for PST. Does anyone know why is this happening? Is there a fix for this issue?

Comment: see my answer & rate it if it helped you! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing this:

In your `/config /application.rb` Set the timezone you want, for my app I did it this way.

```
config.time_zone = 'Mountain Time (US & Canada)'
```

Please letme know if you any probs.

Comment: Hey @uDay, thank for you answer. That works! However, do you know if there is way to this without changing the whole application configuration? It's ok for me if I see the date in UTC in the model, but I would like it to reflect the proper offset. :)

Comment: do `rake time:zones:all` in commandline to see the list of timezones and specify the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this for Central Time (in my model):

```
def start_date
  super.in_time_zone("Central Time (US & Canada)") if super
end

def end_date
  super.in_time_zone("Central Time (US & Canada)") if super
end
```

But I also needed an before_save to properly set the time when the object saved.

**EDIT**: 
I didn't need the before_save after all, as long as my time_zone was set properly in my application.rb file.